# jQuery validate plugin on DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to use the [validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) on a div as shown in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046739/jquery-validator-plugin-without-using-form/1089155#1089155):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#pseudoForm").validate({
    onfocusout:true,
    rules:{
      first_name:"required",
      last_name:"required"
    }
  });
</script>
<!-- whatever -->
<div id="pseudoForm">
  <input type="text" name="first_name"/>
  <input type="text" name="last_name"/>
</div>
```

I have all within a form.

I am getting a bunch of different errors on different browsers.

- **Firefox**: validator in undefined
- **IE8**: 'settings' is null or not an
  object
- **Chrome**: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This isn't the answer you want to hear, but the other answer is incorrect (it may have been right *when it was posted*, but there have been several major jQuery validation plugin changes since then).

[The validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) is (currently) designed to work on a `<form>`, and *only* on a `<form>`.  You can also note that [all of the plugin documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) references a form, not any other generic container.

The plugin itself keeps track of `validator.currentForm` internally, which refers to the `this` of the passed in selector, getting [`.elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.elements), etc off that...it's really not going to work any other way, not the way the current version's written.

*The overall solution/alternative approach here:* call [`.validate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) on the `<form>` element (the jQuery wrapper for it rather) directly, not any other container.  If you need to divide your `<form>` use [`<fieldset>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/fieldset) elements, possibly using the `ignore: ':hidden'` option in `.validate()` if you don't want to validate input fields that aren't visible to the user.

Comment: this is the answer I needed, thanks. I just needed a final word on the topic. Would you be able to provide a link to a question showing that alternative solution or to copy paste a sample in here, or maybe that should be another question? :)

Comment: What if I don't submit the form and instead have a simple button (which doesn't post the form) and I explicitly validate using .validate() on the click of that button? Is that possible?

Comment: @Ismail - In that case, you still use `.validate()` initially to rig up the validation, then use `.valid()` which checks if the form is valid according to the rules you setup.  You can read more on that function here:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid

Comment: Hi, I am getting the exactly same error but I dint call any validate method.... is there any clue why the error is still shown?? My question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473650/error-validator-is-undefined-occured-when-edit-drop-down-list-using-jeditable
Thanks in advance....

Comment: FYI to future readers:  the `contenteditable` attribute is supported as of version 1.15.0

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing bracket. Try this instead:

```
$("#pseudoForm").validate({
    onfocusout:true,
    rules:{
        first_name:"required",
        last_name:"required"
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry the bracket was missing from the question but its in my code, corrected now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same error if you select the form by class

`$(".form_class").validate(...`

instead of by ID
  `$("#form_id").validate(...`

or tag name
  `$("form").validate(...`

Answer (score 0):

Open `jquery.validate.js` or `jquery.validate.min.js` and find(ctrl + F) "*label*" and `replaceAll` with your your required tag:

> Example: div

then perform validation.

Comment: Living life in the fast lane

Answer (score 0):

```
//HTML

<div class="form-group has-feedback col-xs-8 " style="padding-right:0px">
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="Otp_MobileNo" id="mobileNo" placeholder="Mobile No."  minlength="10" maxlength="10">
                <span id="mobileno_message"  style="display:none;color: red;">Please enter a valid Mobile No</span>
            </div>


    //Java Script
     $("#getOtp").click(function(){
         jQuery(document).ready(function(){





            var MobileNo = jQuery("#mobileNo").val();
            var MobileNoLength = MobileNo.length;  
            var zipRegex = /^\d{10}$/;
             var mobileNo = $("#mobileNo").val();

            if (!zipRegex.test(MobileNo))
            { 
               jQuery('#mobileno_message').show();


            }
            else
            { 

              // success!

                 jQuery('#mobileno_message').hide();
                 $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url  : '<?php echo site_url('Login/send_otp'); ?>',
                data : {Otp_MobileNo:mobileNo,},
                dataType    : 'json',
                beforeSend: function()
                { 
                  $("#error").fadeOut();
                },
                success :  function(response)
                { 
                alert(response.message_text);
                $("#check-otp").delay().animate({
                    height: 'toggle',
                  },
                  "slow");
                $("#getOtp").hide();
                }
             });





            }

          });



           });
```