# JQuery validate with several validators per form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, forms

I have a single form with some div blocks inside it. All the divs have their fields and buttons. On button click i need to validate just THAT div(button's parent) and submit some fields to server asynchronously. Everything works fine, but not the validation. I use [JQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). As i see i cant write such code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//.......
     // Validator for general information
        var userProfileGeneralValidator = $("#form1").validate({
            onkeyup: false,
            onclick: false,
            onfocusout: false,
            rules: {
                txtPrivateNumber: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                txtPrivateNumber: {
                    required: "Required!"
                }
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                if (error.text() != "") {

                }
            },
            success: function (lbl) {

            }
        });

       // Validator for password information
        var userPasswordValidator = $("#form1").validate({
            onkeyup: false,
            onclick: false,
            onfocusout: false,
            rules: {
                txtOldPass: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                }
            },
            messages: {
                txtOldPass: {
                    required: "Required!"
                }

            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                if (error.text() != "") {
                }
            },
            success: function (lbl) {

            }
        });
</script>
```

And than call `userPasswordValidator.form()` on one button click and `userProfileGeneralValidator.form()` on other button click. Are there any tricks to achieve my goal: several form parts to validate separately with jquery?
**PS:** found one solution: put several forms in main form. One per div. But think its dirty.
**UPDATE with solution ive used:** in the end i've taken the answer from this question, but made the following changes:
i call the `validate()` method on whole form somewhere in document.ready. As validate options i add rules for all the controls i need to validate(they are nested in some `divs` as groups). Messages/errorPositions/Success i declare in the files, where i works with clicks on the buttons in that divs, where the controls to validate are nested. And to validate just that div i use:

```
var validator = $("#topUserProfile").validate(userProfileGeneralValidator);
// Validate and save general information
if (!validator.form()) {

    return;
}
```

Where `#topUserProfile` is the name of the div that is containing controls; `userProfileGeneralValidator` is variable that holds additional options for validation(messages/ position/ etc). Thank you all, who helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I have used for this requirement is to pass *multiple elements* to the jquery validate plugin **valid()** method, for example some variation of this

```
$('#testdiv :input').valid()
```

If you just call $('#testdiv').valid() this won't work, but with the :input selector the call will tell you whether all of the form elements in the the jquery wrapped set are valid.

Comment: Thank you, the solution is simple, complete and works just fine! So i can just validate any container i like without creating <form>! Strange, couldnt found this in the documentation..Its really outdated and incomplete :(

Comment: mm..tested..not actually working without additional form tags.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4938022/47672

Comment: That is right, the input elements still have to be in a form, but you can use this to validate sections within a form.

Comment: updated the question with the solution. To get there - ive used your answer. Thanks again :) have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this before, but the quickest way is to create one form and initialize the entire thing with one .validate call. Then if you have sub-cases of validation, use individual element targeting with the .valid() method. Read more about that here:
    http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid

Here's how it would look, assuming #txtOldPass is inside #form1:

```
$("#form1").validate();
$("button").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("Valid: " + $("#txtOldPass").valid());
});
```

Comment: The docs may be out of date?  [This page](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) shows that `.element()` is the method (boolean) for checking individual elements; like this:  `$("#myform").validate().element("#myselect");`  Although, I'm leaning towards `.valid()` as being the better way right now.

Comment: Thank you, will test it tomorrow asap.