# jquery validation on "div" tag with type 'Button'

Tags: jquery, validation

Hello i am at learning phase of validation and i am trying to add validation on div tag where i when click on the by clicking on type=button.

here is my code.

```
    <div id="addlblist">
    <select class="myselect2" name="tst">
    </select>
    <select class="myselect2" name="lbname">
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="TestDate" />

    <input type="button" id="btn"/>
</div>
```

here is the jquery code where i set the validation in it.
i want to  that when i click on type button then it calls the client side validation that is required. 
please guide me how to do this.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
                        $("#addlblist").validate({
                            rules: {
                                'tst': {
                                    required: true
                                },
                                'lbname':
                                {
                                    required: true
                                },
                                'TestDate': {
                                    required: true
                                }
                            },
                            messages: {
                                'tst': {
                                    required: "Select Test Name"

                                },
                                'lbname':
                                {
                                    required: "Select Lab Name"
                                },
                                'TestDate': {
                                    required: "Select Date for Test"
                                }

                            },
                            submitHandler: function (form) {
                                form.submit();
                            }

                        })
                    });
            </script>
```

Comment: would be helpful if you could submit a https://jsfiddle.net/ DEMO

Comment: You can get the detailed information here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936221/jquery-validate-plugin-on-div

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery validate plugin on DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936221/jquery-validate-plugin-on-div)

Answer (score 1):

You will need a custom method to validate the select tags `$.validator.addMethod`.

Here is a very basic example of how to solve your issue:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function(value, element, arg){
    return arg !== value;
   }, "Please select an option");

  $("#addlblist").validate({
    submitHandler: function (form) {
      alert('validated');
    },
    rules: {
      'tst': {valueNotEquals: "Default" },
      'lbname': {valueNotEquals: "Default"},
      'TestDate': {required: true}
    },
    messages: {
      'tst': {required: "Select Test Name"},
      'lbname': {required: "Select Lab Name"},
      'TestDate': {required: "Select Date for Test"}
    }
  })
});
```

```css
label.error {
  color: red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<form id="addlblist">
  <p><select class="myselect2" name="tst">
    <option>Default</option>
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
  </select>
  <select class="myselect2" name="lbname">
    <option>Default</option>
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
  </select></p>
  <p><input type="text" name="TestDate" required/></p>
  <p><input id="btn" value="Validate" type="submit"/></p>
</form>
```

Comment: OP question is how to do validation for `div` element not using `form`

Comment: validation plugin works with form and has to have a button with type sumit, if you are worried because that reloads the page, validation plugin allow you to handle that on the `submitHandler` option

Answer (score 0):

in order to make jquery validation try below code, none of other files required.

```js
  var validatstatus;
    function validcheck(currntcheck) {
        validatstatus = true;
        $(currntcheck).closest('div').find('input,div[contenteditable="true"]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val().trim() == '' && $(this).is("input") && $(this).attr('required')) {
                alert($(this).attr('data-required'));
                $(this).focus();
                validatstatus = false;
                return false;
            }
            else if ($(this).text().trim() == '' && $(this).is('div') && $(this).attr('required')) {
                alert($(this).attr('data-required'));
                $(this).focus();
                validatstatus = false;
                return false;
            }

        })
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnis').click(function () {
            validcheck(this);
            if (validatstatus == true) { alert('success'); }
        })
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<div>
        <input type="text" required="true" data-required="please fill Name" />
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" required="true" data-required="please fill address" />
        <div contenteditable="true" style="border:1px solid gray; width:150px;" required="true"
            data-required="please fill message"></div>

        <input type="button" value="check validation" id="btnis" />
    </div>
```

in above code button click call in $(document).ready() method , you can call as onclick.