# Using jQuery Validation plugin for a div instead of form?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate

**NOTE**: I referred these questions [Qn1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046739/jquery-validator-plugin-without-using-form) , [Qn2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936221/jquery-validate-plugin-on-div) before asking this . But honestly the answers are **not working**.  Please suggest a solution..
I am doing validation to my input fields using jquery validation plugin. My code works fine when all the tags are kept inside a form tag and accessing it in jquery like,  `$("#formID").validate()` --> this is working fine... But I want to achieve the same for a `div` instead of a form.

I tried it like this: `$("#divID").validate()` but it's not working...

Below is my code. please take a look and tell me how to achieve it for a `div`.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#content").validate({
            onfocusout: true,
            rules: {
                fullname:
                    {
                    lettersonly: true,
                    required: true
                    },
                age:
                    {
                        required: true,
                        number: true,
                        min: 20,
                        max:98,
                        nowhitespace:true
                    }
            },
            messages: {
                fullname: "Please specify your name.",
                age:"Please enter your correct age."
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="content">
            <p>
                <label for="fullname">Full name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" /><br />
                <label for="age">Age</label>
                <input type="text" name="age" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <button id="submit" value="">Search User</button>
            </p>
 </div>
```

Comment: I think you are going to have to change the validation script because that one only works for forms, according to the documentation: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Options_for_the_validate.28.29_method

Comment: the first question is WHY? Second "Ur name" ?

Comment: Have a form. Even if you are going to process the data with JS, have a form. Forms group controls for the benefit of non-visual tools. Forms continue to work when the JS fails (for whatever reason). Follow the principles of [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: hello @mplungjan . i am working with jquery ajax asynchronous operations. In order to select the field i want to work with (according to the requirement for ajax calls), i  prefer validating 'div' than forms. My name is Ebenezar.

Comment: @mplungjan: sorry..:) , text in the validation ? sorry i dint understand. could you please explain what you want to know one more time.

Comment: `fullname: "please specify ur name",` - it should be `fullname: "please specify your name",` in a serious web page

Comment: @mplungjan: got it. really thanks for helping. any luck with div validation ?

Comment: @Niklas : thank you for the response. so, according to what you are saying, i guess i have to modify the code inside the validation script in order to make the script validate the div on submit instead of form right ? But i wanna know whether it'll work ? can you please give any suggestion about that...

Comment: @Ebenezar_Gislen_Softwares: Ugh, I guess you could go down that path, but I'm afraid we'll never see you again if you do. Changing the script sounds like a nightmare to me. Will it work in the end? I really have no idea, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Niklas: Thats true. i dont wanna burn all my time and end up using the form again. still i'm gonna give it a try.. a little bit atleast:) and please let me know if u find any solution to the requirement. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> **Quote OP:**  "NOTE: I referred these questions Qn1 , [Qn2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936221/jquery-validate-plugin-on-div) before asking this . But honestly the answers are not working."

Incorrect, the [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4938022/594235) on [Qn2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936221/jquery-validate-plugin-on-div) is working perfectly:

> [The validation plugin is (currently) designed to work on a `<form>`,
>   and only on a `<form>`. You can also note that all of the plugin
>   documentation references a `form`, not any other generic container.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4938022/594235)

You **must** use a `form` element with the jQuery Validate plugin.  There is no workaround for this.

However, if you just want to validate some inputs without actually submitting a `form`, there are lots of working solutions.  **Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/GmQ5d/**

**[Full Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not the answer you want to hear, but using the JQuery Validate plugin you can't perform the validation on anything other than a `form` tag. You may note that [all of the plugin documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) references a form and not any other generic container, e.g Div.

This [website](http://www.junnark.com/blog/detail/using-jquery-validation-with-aspnet-web-forms) shows you how to implement JQuery Validate with webforms, not as easy as the normal examples that you get from JQuery, but still good.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's own validation only works for `form`s. This [plugin](http://validity.thatscaptaintoyou.com/Demos/index.htm#UsingValidityWithAjax), however, looks like it should work without forms. According to their documentation that is, I haven't tested it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Very outdated, but seems like it still requires one possible solution to be added. If you cannot use form (in .NET it simply cannot be more than 1 form per page), you can still validate directly each field.

So instead of

```
$("#divID").validate();
```

you can use:

```
var isValid = $("#fullname").validate();
isValid = $("#age").validate();

if(isValid){
// do submit form
}
```